# "The crowd chooses Barabbas" meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idiom-meaning

What is the meaning of the expression "the crowd chooses Barabbas"?

I'm very familiar with the account where the crowds chose to spare Barabbas instead of Jesus, but I'm not sure of the exact meaning or when one could use it.

**EDIT**

I believe the meaning could be something along these lines:
"When people have to choose between the right thing and the convenient thing, they usually pick the latter".

Would this be a correct interpretation of the expression?

Comment: What explanation can be more clear and obvious than the phrase itself? Maybe you question can be improved by stating what you think it means and where your doubts are more precisely.

Comment: @fev thank you! I've edited according to your suggestions

Comment: Even today we are still choosing Barabbas: https://eu.tmnews.com/story/news/2021/04/04/commentary-even-today-were-still-choosing-barabbas/44030405/#:~:text=We%20choose%20Barabbas%20every%20time,when%20we'd%20rather%20not.

Comment: Are you asking about the literal meaning (the choice of tense, or the word choice of 'crowd') or about it's metaphorical meaning outside of the Christian Bible?

Comment: @Mitch The metaphorical meaning outside of the Christian Bible

Comment: Can you give us context? Is it being cited as a general principle, or a description of a specific instance?

Comment: Following up on what @DJClayworth said, can you explain where you saw it outside of a Biblical context? I did a couple of quick searches (on the Web and on Google Books) and only saw results that were directly about the Biblical story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that the statement you read is one of general principle, i.e. meaning "The crowd will always choose Barabbas". It's obviously metaphorical, since the literal choice can only be made once by one crowd.

The choice between Jesus and Barabbas, metaphorically speaking, was one between good and evil. Jesus was (ignoring the religious aspects for simplicity) a good, kind, wise, peaceful, innocent person. Barabbas was a violent rebel bent on killing and the overthrow of government.

What the sentence means is that crowds will always choose the evil over the good. It's possible that, given the context, the author meant something more specific that crowds will always choose, like "the violent over the peaceful", but without knowing the context it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct. There are many other ways to put it. I will try a few:

> Crowds make history but not always truth.
> Crowds ***can*** be manipulated: "But the chief priests and elders persuaded the multitude that they should ask Barabbas, and destroy Jesus". (Matt. 27:20 KJV)
> "... and men loved darkness rather than light, because their deeds were evil". (Jn. 3:19 KJV)
> People choose that which leaves them be, demands nothing from them, does not require the effort to change.